# Javascript not doing anything in asp.net master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am having an issue adding a photo slide show to my asp.net master page. I am working on this project for a friend of mine who needs a website built for her company. I have tried a number of different slide shows as well as coding a few from scratch using tutorials. This is not my main language so I am finding it difficult to spot exactly what is wrong and having tried all possible solutions with no success, I have decided to ask for help.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WingtipToys.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <!--######################Slider Code Start###############################-->

    <title>Featured Content Slider</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/FeaturedContentSlider/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/FeaturedContentSlider/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/FeaturedContentSlider/js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/FeaturedContentSlider/js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/FeaturedContentSlider/js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var theInt = null;
        var $crosslink, $navthumb;
        var curclicked = 0;

        theInterval = function (cur) {
            clearInterval(theInt);

            if (typeof cur != 'undefined')
                curclicked = cur;

            $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
            $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
            $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');

            theInt = setInterval(function () {
                $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
                $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
                $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');
                curclicked++;
                if (6 == curclicked)
                    curclicked = 0;

            }, 3000);
        };

        $(function () {

            $("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();

            $navthumb = $(".nav-thumb");
            $crosslink = $(".cross-link");

            $navthumb
            .click(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                theInterval($this.parent().attr('href').slice(1) - 1);
                return false;
            });

            theInterval();
        });
    </script>
        <!--######################Slider Code End###############################-->
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Wingtip Toys</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" id="adminLink" visible="false" 
                          href="~/Admin/AdminPage">Admin</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/ProductList">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/ShoppingCart" ID="cartCount">&nbsp;</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--######################Slider Code Start###############################-->
        <div id="page-wrap">

    <div class="slider-wrap">
        <div id="main-photo-slider" class="csw">
            <div class="panelContainer">

                <div class="panel" title="Panel 1">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-1.jpg" alt="temp" />
                        <div class="photo-meta-data">
                            Photo Credit: <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/astrolondon/2396265240/">Kaustav Bhattacharya</a><br />
                            <span>"Free Tibet" Protest at the Olympic Torch Rally</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 2">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-2.jpg" alt="temp" />
                        <div class="photo-meta-data">
                            Chicago Bears at Seattle Seahawks<br />
                            <span>Fifth field goal, overtime win for the Seahawks</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 3">
                    <div class="wrapper">

                        <img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/scotch-egg.jpg" alt="scotch egg" class="floatLeft"/>

                        <h1>How to Cook a Scotch Egg</h1>

                        <ul>
                            <li>6 hard-boiled eggs, well chilled</li>
                            <li>1 pound good quality sausage meat</li>
                            <li>1/2 cup AP flour</li>
                            <li>1-2 eggs, beaten</li>
                            <li>3/4 cup panko-style bread crumbs</li>
                            <li>Vegetable oil for frying</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 4">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-4.jpg" alt="temp" />
                        <div class="photo-meta-data">
                            A Poem by Shel Silverstein<br />
                            <span>Falling Up</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 5">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-5.jpg" alt="temp" />
                        <div class="photo-meta-data">
                            New Video on CSS-Tricks<br />
                            <span>Using Wufoo for Web Forms</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 6">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <h1>A Tale of Two Cities</h1>
                        <p><em>Charles Dickins</em></p>
                        <blockquote>It was the best of times</blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#1" class="cross-link active-thumb"><img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-1thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a>
        <div id="movers-row">
            <div><a href="#2" class="cross-link"><img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-2thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
            <div><a href="#3" class="cross-link"><img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-3thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
            <div><a href="#4" class="cross-link"><img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-4thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
            <div><a href="#5" class="cross-link"><img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-5thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
            <div><a href="#6" class="cross-link"><img src="FeaturedContentSlider/images/tempphoto-6thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
        <!--######################Slider Code End###############################-->
        <div id="TitleContent" style="text-align: center">
            <a runat="server" href="~/">
                <asp:Image  ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.jpg" BorderStyle="None" />
            </a>  
            <br />  
        </div>
        <div id="CategoryMenu" style="text-align: center">       
            <asp:ListView ID="categoryList"  
                ItemType="WingtipToys.Models.Category" 
                runat="server"
                SelectMethod="GetCategories" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <b style="font-size: large; font-style: normal">
                    <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductsByCategoryRoute", new {categoryName = Item.CategoryName}) %>">
                        <%#: Item.CategoryName %>
                    </a>
                    </b>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemSeparatorTemplate>  |  </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Wingtip Toys</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So what is currently happening, is that the Style.css file gets accessed, but none of the javascript files seem to be doing anything. The slider is displayed, but all the images are placed vertically one underneath each other, so I have a long line of images running vertically down the page. Sorry if the formatting is off or if there is not enough detail, this is my first post on here, I usually figure things out on my own. Thanks for the help!!

Edit:

I removed the tilda "~" from the javascript paths and the java files seem to be found, When I press F12 or "Ctrl + shift + j" i get the following error: "Uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function" on the line: "$("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();"

Edit 2:

I cant upload screen shots of the console output as my reputation is a stunning 1 point, but the following are listed under Frames->Default->Scripts in the console output.

> jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js,  jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js, 
>   jquery-1.2.6.min.js,  coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js,  jquery-1.10.2.js, 
>   ycodaslider-2.0.pack.js,

here is the code in an index.html file that works, it just doesn't work when I try and do the same in my site.master page.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <title>Featured Content Slider</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var theInt = null;
    var $crosslink, $navthumb;
    var curclicked = 0;

    theInterval = function(cur) {
      clearInterval(theInt);

      if (typeof cur != 'undefined')
        curclicked = cur;

      $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
      $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
      $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');

      theInt = setInterval(function() {
        $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
        $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
        $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');
        curclicked++;
        if (6 == curclicked)
          curclicked = 0;

      }, 3000);
    };

    $(function() {

      $("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();

      $navthumb = $(".nav-thumb");
      $crosslink = $(".cross-link");

      $navthumb
        .click(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          theInterval($this.parent().attr('href').slice(1) - 1);
          return false;
        });

      theInterval();
    });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="page-wrap">

    <div class="slider-wrap">
      <div id="main-photo-slider" class="csw">
        <div class="panelContainer">

          <div class="panel" title="Panel 1">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <img src="images/tempphoto-1.jpg" alt="temp" />
              <div class="photo-meta-data">
                Photo Credit: <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/astrolondon/2396265240/">Kaustav Bhattacharya</a>
                <br />
                <span>"Free Tibet" Protest at the Olympic Torch Rally</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel" title="Panel 2">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <img src="images/tempphoto-2.jpg" alt="temp" />
              <div class="photo-meta-data">
                Chicago Bears at Seattle Seahawks
                <br />
                <span>Fifth field goal, overtime win for the Seahawks</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel" title="Panel 3">
            <div class="wrapper">

              <img src="images/scotch-egg.jpg" alt="scotch egg" class="floatLeft" />

              <h1>How to Cook a Scotch Egg</h1>

              <ul>
                <li>6 hard-boiled eggs firm up)</li>
                <li>1 pound good quality</li>
                <li>1/2 cup AP flour</li>
                <li>1-2 eggs, beaten</li>
                <li>3/4 cup panko-style bread crumbs</li>
                <li>Vegetable oil for frying</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel" title="Panel 4">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <img src="images/tempphoto-4.jpg" alt="temp" />
              <div class="photo-meta-data">
                A Poem by Shel Silverstein
                <br />
                <span>Falling Up</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel" title="Panel 5">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <img src="images/tempphoto-5.jpg" alt="temp" />
              <div class="photo-meta-data">
                New Video on CSS-Tricks
                <br />
                <span>Using Wufoo for Web Forms</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel" title="Panel 6">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <h1>A Tale of Two Cities</h1>
              <p><em>Charles Dickins</em>
              </p>
              <blockquote>It was the best of times, en, we were all going direct</blockquote>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#1" class="cross-link active-thumb">
        <img src="images/tempphoto-1thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" />
      </a>
      <div id="movers-row">
        <div>
          <a href="#2" class="cross-link">
            <img src="images/tempphoto-2thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#3" class="cross-link">
            <img src="images/tempphoto-3thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#4" class="cross-link">
            <img src="images/tempphoto-4thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#5" class="cross-link">
            <img src="images/tempphoto-5thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#6" class="cross-link">
            <img src="images/tempphoto-6thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Here is a link to the slider I am trying to use: http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-slick-auto-playing-featured-content-slider/ the index.html the came with the slider works. but I cant get that same functionality to work inside my site.master.

Comment: Did you try inspecting the Chrome Devtools/Firebug for any errors and whether the JS files have been actually loaded??

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get the following error when I go into chromes dev tools (ctrl + shift + j). "Uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function" on the line: "$("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();"

Comment: Try starting your javascript src with `"/`. Your current paths will break if you aren't in the root directory. `src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"` should be `src="/js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"` Same goes for your image sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try using script source without "**~**". Starting with "**/**" is enough to reach root in HTML. "**~**" is available on server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I removed the tilde but still no success. I get the following error when I go into chromes dev tools (ctrl + shift + j). "Uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function" on the line: "$("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();"

Comment: Are you sure codaSlider is included and loaded correctly? You can see this by selecting Resources tab from console and dig through Frames > ... > Scripts and seeing codaSilder JS here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your images are displayed, albeit not in the Slider, you should look at the browser dev tools [F12] to verify:

- all page resources are loaded i.e. status codes are all 200
- look for JavaScript errors in the console

Write some console.log and console.debug statements throughout your JavaScript to help triage where things are not as expected.

Ensure all the css selectors referenced in the JavaScript will map to something e.g.

```
.stripNav ul li a
```